# Read a file containing multiple entries and output one entry based on user input

Tags: java, file, for-loop

I am new to java and this might sound really stupid but !
Assume you have this txt file somewhere in your pc

The_txt.txt

Anthony

anthonyk@somewhere.com

01234567891

location

---

Maria

maria@somewhere.com

1234561234

location2

---

George

george@somewhere.com

1234512345

location3

---

What i want to do with this txt is that , I prompt the user to insert a Phone number so if for example the user provides Maria's phone number (1234561234) the program will output

Maria

maria@somewhere.com

1234561234

location2

My piece of code for this task :

```
    private static void Search_Contact_By_Phone(File file_location){

        Scanner To_Be_String = new Scanner(System.in);

        String To_Be_Searched = To_Be_String.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\n \n \n");

        BufferedReader Search_Phone_reader;
        try {
            Search_Phone_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (file_location));
            String new_line = Search_Phone_reader.readLine();
            while (new_line != null) {
                if (To_Be_Searched.equals(new_line)){
                    for (int i=0;i<=3;i++){
                        System.out.println(new_line);
                        new_line = Search_Phone_reader.readLine();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                new_line = Search_Phone_reader.readLine();
            }
            Search_Phone_reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Should your program search by number or by any line? Do you have any delimeters between your users?

Comment: I have another void to search by name but i have done that one .My problem is with by searching by phone number .
No i don't have any delimeters if it counts every time a new user is added to the txt the program adds _____________________ and \n after each addition

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase. For example, `To_Be_String` should be `toBeString`.

Comment: Yes,it can be delimeter. Anyway,you can divide your user with regex like that Name-only letters,mail-consists @, number-have only numbers, and location-have only letters with number in the end. So,when you input some line into Scanner,you should search your first delimeter ______\n before and start add full user into String[] .

Comment: Oh,I suppose,you can add into your String[] user each line till delimeter,if you searching line is found in array you show that user,if not,you delete []user and recreate. So on each iteration, You'll have 4 lines in array and check it on your inputed string

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.mycompany.io;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // For a small file
    Path path = Paths.get("The_txt.txt");
    String toBeSearched = "1234512345";
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // Better performance if i starts at 2 and i += 4
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
      if (lines.get(i).equals(toBeSearched)) {
        System.out.println(lines.get(i - 2));
        System.out.println(lines.get(i - 1));
        System.out.println(lines.get(i));
        System.out.println(lines.get(i + 1));
      }
    }
    // Else
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
      String line1;
      while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String line2 = reader.readLine();
        String line3 = reader.readLine();
        if (line3.equals(toBeSearched)) {
          // Found
          System.out.println(line1);
          System.out.println(line2);
          System.out.println(line3);
          System.out.println(reader.readLine());
          break;
        } else {
          reader.readLine();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How yo can do `lines.get(i-1)` if you're not sure that it's exist?

Comment: If the format of the file is good, it should exist because of the test in the "if". My code is just a quick code that can be modified according to your wish. I forgot to close the flow, I have to leave now but I will add it soon.